# Upgraded to 2.3, now ant builds don't include the jars in my libs directory

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

I've been doing all my builds using ant on the command line (Ubuntu 10.04). I loaded up the 2.3 SDK and made the necessary path changed (platform-tools). Now my builds don't include the jars in my libs directory. Any thoughts on what I need to change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Ant build system now requires Ant 1.8+
Unfortunately it "works" (broken) with 1.7 because we rely on a new behavior in 1.8, not a new task or attribute that would break 1.7

Answer (score 0):

i'm not familiar with the ant builde for android as i'm usig eclipse(why shouldn't ou ? it generates build.xml autotmatically).
In any case whe you say platform tools you mean $ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-9 ?
Are you sure it's needed for ant ? i know the ant build file itself is pretty empty and most of the work is done in their java .sh files so it's ard to tell what they are missing, cold it be you found a bug in their new SDK ?

Comment: I have just found it easier to use ant for various reason. In the past, ant just picked up jars in the libs directory (no need to add them to the build path). It is also faster without the overhead of eclipse, and release builds are one step ("ant release") once you set up the jar signing info. I use eclipse when I need to debug, but ant the rest of the time. It just worked. Eclipse builds work for me in 2.3 as expeted.

Comment: The build path includes $ANDROID_HOME/tools and the new $ANDROID_HOME/platform_tools. I added $ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-9 just to be safe. 

Just worked before,not now

Answer (score 0):

I've got other more serious problems with SDK2.3 (the AVDs are bust). I'd set up Ant builds OK to work on 2.2 and was looking to see if an Ant build would run. My custom build.xml overrode quite a bit of the stuff in ant_rules_r3.xml but still used some of it. I noticed that this has now been removed and replaced with main_rules.xml, which is a bit different. 'project.libraries' replaces 'android.libraries' for one thing. It's probably worth you looking at the differences if your build.xml was based on ant_rules_3.

I'm not going to look at it myself until my main problem is fixed.

Comment: Yeah, stuff definitely changed at the ant level. I'm pretty much using the stock ant rules. I can even generate basic android-9 project, put the jars in libs, and compile getting the same result. Not sure if they intended this change or broke something (my guess). Either way I'll have to dig into the ant rules to fix it. The good news is one update came out today, so hopefully a stock fix is upcoming.